# Returning all rows falling within a time period

Tags: sql

I have a doubt in writing sql.

I had a farmerfields table with

```
YEAR,SEASON,Number of Fields.
```

and season look like this

```
Kharif---- 15june-15Oct   
Rabi---15 oct to 15 Feb   
Summer----15Feb to 15 June
```

now i want to write sql which returns all the rows excluding the current season in the current year. ie we should get the current season based on system date.

I am cracking my brain to get this, but could not.

Please help me.

Comment: What RDBMS? Date functions vary. Also am confused about your structure. Are you saying that the season column contains strings like `Kharif---- 15june-15Oct`? If so you should read up on normalisation first.

Comment: Yest martin. Season contains string.There is seasons table which contains start month, end month, season name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table structure is wrong and not fit for what you need.

Instead of single field called SEASON, have two fields: SEASON_START and SEASON_END both of type Date then the query is as simple as:

```
Select * From [farmerfields] Where GetDate() Between SEASON_START And SEASON_END
```

If the names are part of your current SEASON field, add third field SEASON_NAME as well and the new structure will be:

```
SEASON_NAME | SEASON_START | SEASON_END
---------------------------------------
Kharif      | 15june       | 15Oct   
Rabi        | 15 oct       | 15 Feb
...
```

Edit: in my above sample code I assumed you have SQL Server database - in case of different database you'll have different function to get current system date.

Comment: Actually I have a seasons table from which I am getting seasons and storing it here.seasons table contain season name, start date, end date

Comment: Good, so use the `Where GetDate() Between SEASON_START And SEASON_END` and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you define a seasons table with three rows as above, e.g.

```
create table season (
  season_id              int,
  description            varchar(32),
  start_day_of_month     int,
  start_month            int   
  end_day_of_month       int,
  end_month              int   
)
```

the year is not included here just the day of month and month indices.

Your farmerfields table should then have a seaon_id column referring to this and most likely have a year column too.

Depending on your SQL vendor different date functions will be available but should should be able to compose a start and end date using the year from farmerfields and the month and day-of-month from season. Given this you can then determine if the current date falls within a given farmerfield entry's start and end dates.

Answer (score 0):

For difference of dates you can use the sql function DATEDIFF

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2011-10-20' AND '2011-1-1' AND DATEDIFF(`date`, '2011-10-20') % 10 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you define a seasons table with three rows as above, e.g.

```
create table season (
  season_id              int,
  description            varchar(32),
  start_day_of_month     int,
  start_month            int   
  end_day_of_month       int,
  end_month              int   
)
```

The year is not included here just the day of month and month indices.

Your farmerfields table should then have a `season_id` column referring to this and most likely have a year column too.

Depending on your SQL vendor different date functions will be available but should should be able to compose a start and end date using the year from farmerfields and the month and day-of-month from season. Given this you can then determine if the current date falls within a given farmerfield entry's start and end dates.